# Compilation error when adding a generic object to a list

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

Why does `list.Add(new B())` compile and `list.Add(new Wrapper<B>())` not compile?  I thought that either both or neither would compile because I thought the compiler would be able to figure out that the implicit cast of `B` returns a `Wrapper<B>` which is that same type produced from `new Wrapper<B>()`.  I'm using C# 4 in VS 2012.

```
class Wrapper<T> where T : new()
{
    public static implicit operator Wrapper<T>(T obj)
    {
        return new Wrapper<T>();
    }
    public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> obj)
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
class A { }
class B : A { }
class MyClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Wrapper<A>> list = new List<Wrapper<A>>();
        //This line compiles and runs successfully
        list.Add(new B());
        //This line doesn't compile
        list.Add(new Wrapper<B>());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be editing answers into the question.  You should only be editing the question to clarify the question that you're asking.  Answers to the questions should be in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from your question that you think that adding an instance of `B` to a list of `Wrapper<A>` works because `B` is implicitly cast to a `Wrapper<B>`, which is somehow added to the list.  However, this isn't what happening.  In fact, the compiler cannot cast from `Wrapper<B>` to `Wrapper<A>` in one step.

The reason adding an instance of `B` to a list of `Wrapper<A>` works is because the compiler sees that `B` extends `A` and that there is a user-defined implicit cast from `A` to `Wrapper<A>`.

You might think that you can also add a `Wrapper<B>` to a list of `Wrapper<A>` because there is a user-defined implicit cast from `Wrapper<B>` to `B` and `B` extends `A` and there is a user-defined implicit cast from `A` to `Wrapper<A>`.  However, you cannot chain together user-defined implicit casts in this way, according to the specs (section 6.4.4 detailed [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552)).  In fact, the minimal example need not even deal with generics.  Consider this simple example of the problem:

```
class A 
{
    public static implicit operator B(A a) { return default(B); }
}
class B
{
    public static implicit operator C(B a) { return default(C); }
}
class C
{
    public static void Method(C c) { }
}
public static void Main()
{
    C.Method(new A());
}
```

Of course, if you explicitly do the cast, then it works:

```
public static void Main()
{
    C.Method((B)new A());
}
```

Comment: This is describing how to get the second line to compile, but the second line *already compiles and runs fine*.  The compiler *does* apply two implicit conversion operators in this context (because one of them isn't a user defined operator).

Comment: @Servy: Ben is correct here. The original poster is expecting a conversion from `Wrapper<B>` to `Wrapper<A>` to go through the following steps: `Wrapper<B>` to `B` via user-defined implicit conversion, `B` to `A` via implicit reference conversion, `A` to `Wrapper<A>` via user-defined implicit reference conversion, and that's *two* user-defined conversions. The C# language will allow *built-in* conversions to be inserted on either side of a user-defined conversion, but will not allow a second *user-defined* conversion in the chain.

Comment: Ok so `list.Add(new Wrapper<B>())` wont work because it requires two implicit casts and `list.Add((B)new Wrapper<B>()))` works because it only requires one implicit cast.  Similiarly, `list.Add(new B())` only requires one implicit cast while `list.Add(new Wrapper<B>))` requires two.  However, `list.Add((B)new Wrapper<B>))` should work because it only requires one.

Comment: @EricLippert The following line from the question: "that the implicit cast of B returns a `Wrapper<B>`" leads me to believe that he thinks that `new B()` is converted to a `Wrapper<B>` and that a `Wrapper<B>` can be added to a `List<Wrapper<A>>`.  What indication do you see in the question that the OP is expecting a `Wrapper<B>` to be converted to a `B` and then from there to a `Wrapper<A>`?

Comment: @steaks Be careful with your language - you cannot chain together user-defined implicit casts.  The conversion from `B` to `A` is an implicit conversion, but not user defined.

Comment: @Servy: The question points out that `Add(B)` works and asks why `Add(Wrapper<B>)` does not. My thought was that the OP understood that `Add(B)` works because `B`-->`A`-->`Wrapper<A>`. But that thought was likely wrong; in reviewing the first paragraph of the question, it seems more likely that the OP is instead expecting `B`-->`Wrapper<B>`-->`Wrapper<A>`. Figuring out precisely how someone is reasoning incorrectly is difficult; that's why compiler error messages are still so bad.

Comment: @EricLippert You're correct. My understanding was that `B`->`Wrapper<B>`->`Wrapper<A>` where I didn't understand how we were getting from `Wrapper<B>` to `Wrapper<A>`.  I'm glad I understand that `B`->`A`->`Wrapper<A>`.  I'm also glad I understand why `Wrapper<B>`->`B`->`A`->`Wrapper<A>` is invalid because that wasn't clear after I understood `B`->`A`->`Wrapper<A>`

Answer (score -2):

`list.Add(new B());` is *not* adding a new `Wrapper<B>` to the list.  It's adding a new `Wrapper<A>` to the list.

The compiler is able to determine that the type expected is `Wrapper<A>`, and that there's an implicit conversion from what's there `new B()` to a `Wrapper<A>` because the operand for a `Wrapper<A>` needs to accept an `A` object, and `new B()` *is* a type of `A`.

`list.Add(new Wrapper<B>());` doesn't work because you're not *allowed* to add a `Wrapper<B>` to a `List<Wrapper<A>>` because `List` is not covariant.

Comment: although he has defined implicit casts from `Wrapper<B>` to `B` and `A` to `Wrapper<A>`, and since `B` extends `A`, you might expect this to work.  In other words, if the compiler did allow chaining together implicit casts, this would work.

Comment: @BenReich That doesn't seem to be the expecation of the OP.  His explanation would seem to indicate that he thinks that the second line adds a `Wrapper<B>` to the list.  It doesn't.  He doesn't seem to be expecting it to convert the `Wrapper<B>` to  `B` and then from there to a `Wrapper<A>`, based on his question.

Comment: Ok so the compiler can realize that the implicit cast from `B` to `Wrapper<T>` can return a `Wrapper<A>` because it realizes that it needs a `Wrapper<A>` and `B` is a `A`.  Makes sense.